# How to avoid exception for this JavaFX sample program?

Tags: java, javafx

I try to run the JavaFX sample program, Henley Car Sales, from Oracle [site][1], 
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/samples/DataApp/

[1]: ,http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/samples/DataApp/, I tried it on two different machines and on three different browsers on each machine. It will only up for few seconds and then get the following exception:

```
Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/samples/DataApp/DataAppClient.jar
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.<clinit>(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I do have the latest Java installed. I don't know what I can do to make it working.

**EDIT:**

Above link is a valid link and the JavaFX application is there and can be downloaded to your browser automatically after the click. My browsers can run it but only few seconds due to the exception I pasted.

Comment: I don't think the Henley sales application is supported by Oracle anymore.  It is no longer linked from the [Oracle JavaFX samples page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html).  The source for the Henley sales application is also not distributed with the JavaFX 8 sample source and it is [not in the open-jfx 8 source repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/e408de8061cb/apps).  It may just be an oversight that the application is still hosted on an Oracle download server.

Comment: That link is a valid link and the application is launched but will die after few seconds due to the exception I provided.

Comment: You could [file an issue report with Oracle](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) requesting them to fix the program at the link provided so that it has a better chance of running inside some modern browsers and Java runtimes, but I think it is more likely that they would take the link down than fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm :

> **Note:** The DataApp sample has multiple NetBeans projects and cannot be run without some additional setup. The DataAppReadme.html file and the NetBeans project file are in the src\DataApp directory.

Everything else you have to know is explained on that site.

Comment: If you want to build it and you need the NetBeans and others. But the link I have is a ready demo. It can be launched automatically. Basically the Hanley Car Sales is a web application by using JavaFX, I think.